# how to distinguish from dynamic loaded script and normal src scripts

Tags: javascript

How can I distinguish from dynamic loaded script and normal script included using src property? For example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="static.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('script').src = 'dynamic.js');
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// I want to distinguish dynamic.js and static.js script tags
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve? This smells like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242).

Comment: Bit of a waste of time though if the intention is to remove the scripts. By the time the script is available in the DOM, it's content has been parsed and has become part of the environment. Removing the element does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Add a specific HTML5 `data-*` attribute to the dynamic scripts:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("data-is-dynamic", "true");
script.id = "script1";
script.src = "dynamic.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

An option for getting the `<head>` element is to use `document.head`, although it's not supported in older browsers. Here's the MDN docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.head

Then to distinguish later, use:

```
var someScript = document.getElementById("script1"); // or any script tag you want to analyze
if (someScript.getAttribute("data-is-dynamic") === "true") {
    // is dynamic
} else {
    // is static
}
```

Of course, at the same time, you can set an attribute on static script tags, like `data-is-static`, and then check for that in the opposite manner.

This allows you to validly set a "flag" on a script tag that you can retrieve later.

Comment: @DaggNabbit Very true, except it's not supported in older browsers. It's a definite option, so I'll add it in. I just used what the OP had :)

Comment: @RobG I have no idea what you're referring to. What element is being removed? The OP didn't reveal their reasoning for needing to distinguish, so I just explained my idea

Comment: Comment was supposed to be to the OP, moved. The OP hasn't revealed why the distinction is necessary, so it's not possible to evaluate what might be reasonable solution.

Comment: @RobG Ahh okay, no problem. Well I agree, but I just tried to answer the immediate question. Definitely best to determine the purpose though :)